# MPAndroidChart draw multiple charts lined vertically with shared X axis

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I wonder if it is possible to achieve something like this with MPAndroidChart library?

[image]

Basically, I want to have multiple line charts with different Y axis stacked vertically sharing the same X axis (when I move, zoom or highlight a value I want them to be synchronized). If I get it right, there is no explicit support for this behavior.

I tried to manipulate the values (set negative ones with offset) of the second dataset and I was able to achieve the desired charts placement. But I couldn't find a way to draw the values correctly on the Y axis (AxisValueFormatter isn't enough because I need alternate granularity).

Now I'm thinking of having multiple charts glued together and synchronized by callbacks and zoom/move/highlight them programmatically. But I fear it may affect the performance since I need to work with thousands of data points.

Any ideas? I may even take a look at other free libraries if they can do it, but I prefer to stick with MPAndroidChart as I have good experience with it.

Comment: The  CombinedChart isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: As far as I know, CombinedChart can't do that, it allows only two axis, left and right